# Do Fatty Acid Synthase Inhibitors Selectively induce Apoptosis in Cancer cells without inducing the same in healthy human cells?

Tags: cancer, fatty-acid-synthase, apoptosis

Do Fatty Acid Synthase (FAS) Inhibitors (e.g. cerulenin) selectively induce apoptosis in cancer cells without inducing the same in healthy human cells?

Comment: "Inhibition of fatty acid synthase (FAS) suppresses HER2/neu (erbB-2) oncogene overexpression in cancer cells" http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC490000/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this reference: ["Inhibition of fatty acid synthase (FAS) suppresses HER2/neu (erbB-2) oncogene overexpression in cancer cells"](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC490000/).   Cerulenin is not a magic bullet, but in some cases it may help.